# How to add axis labels for individual entries in the Y-axis using plot() in R

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting a series of time intervals against a character vector of a length of 130. Currently, the y-axis labels are numbered from 0-120 by 20s.

Is there a way to replace the numbered y-axis labels with text labels that show what variety corresponds to what time interval?

Here is an image of the plot I'm describing as it currently is:

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Perhaps the following tips on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot without the labels and then add your custom labels.

```
plot(1:3,  yaxt = "n")
axis(side = 2, at = 1:3, labels = c("a","b", "c"))
```